# What is \uffff in c#

Tags: c#

when I'm trying to do

```
char c = (char)-1;
```

I'm getting compiler error stating that Constant value '-1' cannot be converted to a 'char'

which leads me thinking that this is an invalid conversion. But when I do this in runtime im getting back the character `'\uffff'`.

Out of curiosity what is that character and why does the compiler not like it?

Comment: `char` essentially has the same range as `ushort`. If you dynamically cast `-1` to a `ushort` you have an underflow and it wraps the value around to `ushort.MaxValue`. In your case, the exact same thing is happening and you are getting back `char.MaxValue`. Curiously `char.MaxValue` is the value used in the Roslyn lexer to identify an invalid character because it doesn't represent a valid UTF-16 character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C# uses Unicode UTF-16 to encode strings and chars. `ffff` in UTF-16 is a "non-character".  When you prefix a string with `\u` it tells C# to treat the following characters as a Unicode code point.  So here, your code point is `ffff` in hexadecimal or `65535` in decimal. `char` in C# is represented as a `ushort` under the hood, and there is an implicit conversion between the two.  Here `-1` exceeds the range of `ushort` and overflows to `ushort.MaxValue` which is `65535`. (Integer arithmetic in C# does not throw exceptions on overflow by default.  To enable this behavior use `checked` blocks.)